# Not sure of why count is different when using these 2 measures I created

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got a slicer where I can select the end date of a date range.

[image]

Then I got a measure called "Date Selected" that just obtains the date selected on the slicer

```
Date Selected = max(MachineData[StartTime])
```

Then I got 2 different measures

```
Test1 = COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData,
MachineData[StartTime] >= Max(MachineData[StartTime]) - 31 ))

Test2 = COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData,
MachineData[StartTime] >= MachineData[Date Selected] - 31))
```

Test1 gives me a result of 3800 and Test2 gives me a result of 18k

Why are they fiving me different results? isn't Max(MachineData[StartTime]) supposed to be the same as MachineData[Date Selected] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, this is do to context transition and lack thereof in the first measure.

The `Test1` measure is not equivalent to `Test2` and this is due to the fact that when using a measure within another measure, you are actually using an implicit `CALCULATE` function.

For the two measures to be equivalent, you'd need to write the first one like this:

`Test1 = COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData, MachineData[StartTime] >= CALCULATE(Max(MachineData[StartTime])) - 31 ))`

The reason why your `Test1` measure outputs different results is because `MAX(MachineData[StartTime])` is calculated at the query context, not at the row context of the filtered table. `CALCULATE` introduces row context, which means that the max date calculation occurs for every row of the MachineData table, which in turn makes the filter condition true for each row in the table (you actually reduce the condition in the `FILTER` function to `0 >= -31`).

Try this instead to achieve what you want within the `Test2` measure:

```
Test2 = 
VAR selDate = [Date Selected]*

RETURN
COUNTROWS(FILTER(MachineData,
MachineData[StartTime] >= selDate - 31))
```

Please read more on context transition [here (sqlbi)](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/)

*As a side note - it is not advised to use table qualifiers for measures